# How to save output of pyPDF2 into an Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, extract, pypdf

The following code prints what I need it to (format is not ideal but that may be irrelevant if I can find out how to save as an excel file).

```
for i in range(3,167):
    print(reader.pages[i].extract_text().split('\n'))
```

I've tried using Pandas to save the output:

```
for i in range(3,167):
    (reader.pages[i].extract_text().split('\n')).to_excel('output.xlsx', index = False)
```

I'm not proficient in Python. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. I couldn't understand how to use Camelot all too well.

Answer (score 0):

try to parse what you need from your pdf and then save dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

#store the data
data = []

for i in range(3, 167):
    text = reader.pages[i].extract_text()
    lines = text.split('\n')
    data.extend(lines)

# DataFrame from the list
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Text'])

# Save it to an Excel file
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```